# top not working

Tags: shell-script, cron, top

My below cronjob is not working. What am I doing wrong here??

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/top -n1 | head -10 >>/tmp/load.txt
```

Comment: */5 * * * * /usr/bin/top -n1 | head -10 >>/tmp/load.txt

Comment: Anything in the logs?

Comment: Nothing its blank :(

Comment: Sure that crond is running?

Comment: Tried to specify full path to `head` too? `*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/top -n1 | /usr/bin/head -10 >>/tmp/load.txt`

Comment: Is this a global cronjob or a user cronjob? Did you make sure to have an empty line at the end of your file?

Comment: It's an empty file and /usr/bin/head also not worked for me ..Still the file is blank... ANy other way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `top` from procps on Linux at least needs the `$TERM` environment variable to know how to display things like reverse color and cursor positioning when not in batch mode

So either run:

```
top -bn1 | head
```

Or:

```
TERM=dumb top -n1 | head
```

Or if you need the output suitable for any  given terminal, specify it as

```
TERM=my-terminal top -n1 | head
```

Comment: Good One !!!! gr8 Stephane !!! you rock !!! Thanks for the help !!!